# changes not propagated from controller to view

Tags: ember.js

I thought that executing update would update the view:

```
EmberApp.BlogController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   productName: 'test',

   update : function() {
      this.set('productName', 'll');
   }

});
```

The template is

```
<div>
{{productName}}
</div>
```

test is displayed. But calling update has no effect.

I call update like this:

```
 onChange : function(e) {
        var myController = EmberApp.__container__.lookup('controller:Blog');
        myController.update();
    }, // onChange event from KendoUI grid
```

Regards
 Roger

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with this. I think that would be more easy, to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use `send` to invoke methods on your controller.

Try this instead:

```
onChange : function(e) {
  var myController = EmberApp.__container__.lookup('controller:Blog');
  myController.send('update');
}, // onChange event from KendoUI grid
```

Hope it helps.